# Any Rails projects that allow community blogging?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blogs

I've been looking on Github for a Rails project that allows anyone to sign in and add a blog entry.

Has anyone seen something like this?

Answer (score 1):

TYPO is a blogging platform that uses Ruby on Rails: 
https://github.com/fdv/typo/wiki  looks to have the capability for multiple authors.

The article [here](http://vpanchal.blogspot.com/2007/07/choosing-rails-blogging-system.html) gives a good overview of several other RoR blogging platforms that are out there.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO this is quite easy to make. Especially if you use the twitter-auth gem. Just sign-in with your twitter account, write a post and be done with it.